# Mage::getStoreConfig in PHTML

Tags: magento-1.9, coding-standards

We're on `Magento 1.9.3.4` and we want to display the phone number in the header.

Is it ok to just put into `header.phtml`

```
<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/phone') ?>
```

or is it better to put it into a block and then just call it with

```
<?php echo  $this->getStoreNumber ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible I would add new block to `header.phtml` via `my_layout.xml` and use `$this->getChildHtml('my_block')` (or use an existing one).

I'd prefer `<?php echo  $this->getStoreNumber() ?>` to seperate logic and view. In addition you will be able to rewrite this block and manipulate `getStoreNumber()` method.

Answer (score 3):

According to the "laws" of separating business logic and presentational logic (i.e. controllers/blocks/templates), it would be better to put logic in the Block class, and only use display logic in the templates/views.

But since this is simply a single variable you retrieve from the backend, I think you can just use:

`Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/phone')`

in your template.

There are exceptions however, for example imagine that the phone number would contain a comma separated list, it would be better to extract the phonenumbers in the Block than in the template, because that's easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Its just simple query to database no need to join query and all ,

So Its not time consuming that's why magento allows you to fetch config value in `CMS block` or `CMS page`

So Its ok to use

```
<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/phone') ?>
```

If you want to show phone number at multiple places then I believe

You should go with block and

```
<?php echo  $this->getStoreNumber ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

it is saved in **core_config_data** table, and the phone information is the field:

```
general/store_information/phone
```

So, all you need is to read the configuration data as

```
$storePhone = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/phone');
```

For CMS pages insert the following variable

```
{{config path="general/store_information/phone"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in using below code in `header.phtml`  because everytime it will take dynamic value so if you change phone number in future then it will automatically change in header of your website.

`Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/phone');`

Comment: care to explain?

Comment: @BornCoder better leave an answer instead of writing explainations for others :)

Comment: Sorry guys, thought some time quick answer is better tha long explanayion :) the thing is both options will run prettty same results. So, if you like first options, feel free to use ut